# Perl: Getting UTF-8 file with Mechanize content_file

Tags: file, perl, utf-8, get, mechanize

Creating a perl script (Strawberry Perl v5.32.0 on W10) to download my Google Calendar. Google provides a 'private' (no login required) url to a 'basic.ics' file.
When opening this url in my browser (firefox), a window pops up to download this 'basic.ics' file. When saved, the file is UTF-8 encoded.

In my script I'm using `WWW::Mechanize get ":content_file"` to download the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize;

# URL modified for obvious reasons ...
my $url = 'https://calendar.google.com/path-to-private-calendar-file/basic.ics';
my $local_file_name = 'Calendar.ics';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );
```

The file received with `$mech->get` however, is written ANSI-encoded and contains 'gibberich' (not 'translated' UTF-8 data, I suppose).

How can I make the `get :content_file` create the local file UTF-8 encoded ?

Or do I just download the file as is and convert it to UTF-8 later ?
If so please point me in the right direction, because reading the ANSI-encoded file as UTF-8 does not do the trick ...

Comment: Yes it seems like some sort of encrypted file. The first 16 bytes in hex is: "1f8b 0800 0000 0000 0000 4c8e d10a 8230". The file looks normal if I download it from Google Chrome using the same URL

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with UTF-8 or character encodings. You are getting a gzip-compressed response.

---

If Compress::Zlib is available, WWW::Mechanize provides the following header by default:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

This allows the remote end to compress the response. If it does, the remote end will provide the following header in the response:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

This is happening here, and you are saving the compressed response.

---

You could use `:content_cb` instead of `:content_file` to provide a callback that decompresses the data and stores it. Or you could simply request an uncompressed version by providing the following header:

```
Accept-Encoding: identity
```

This is done using

```perl
$mech->get($url,
   Accept_Encoding => 'identity',
   ":content_file" => $local_file_name,
);
```

If you don't otherwise need the overhead of WWW::Mechanize, why not use its base class [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent). It doesn't provide an `Accept-Encoding` by default, so the server is unlikely to gzip the response

```perl
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

# Will work 99.999% of the time.
$ua->get($url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name);  

# Definitely works.
$ua->get($url,
   Accept_Encoding => 'identity',
   ":content_file" => $local_file_name,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late reply, but I had some other items to handle.
Thanks to ikegami and Hakon for your replies and solutions.

From your replies, I have distilled 4 methods that get a readable UTF-8 encoded non-zipped result file:

- Mechanize + Content_file and encoding
- UserAgent + Content_file, no encoding
- UserAgent + Content_file and encoding
- UserAgent + print content to file

In the last case, however, there was an extra `CR` at the end of each line (`CRCRLF` instead of `CRLF`), but nothing a little regex can't solve ...

Here is the result of my tests:

```
 CASE 1: Mechanize + Content_file and encoding ... 
 Get: $mech1->get($url, Accept_Encoding => 'identity', ":content_file" => $fn1) 
 Calendar1.ics received, size = 78564 bytes 

 CASE 2: UserAgent + Content_file, no encoding ... 
 Get: $ua2->get($url, ":content_file" => $fn2); 
 Calendar2.ics received, size = 78564 bytes 

 CASE 3: UserAgent + Content_file and encoding ... 
 Get: $ua3->get($url, Accept_Encoding => 'identity', ":content_file" => $fn3); 
 Calendar3.ics received, size = 78564 bytes 

 CASE 4: UserAgent + print content to file ... 
 Get: my $res4 = $ua4->get($url); 
          ... 
          my $content = $res4->content; 
          $content =~ s/\r[\n]*/\n/gm; 
          print $fh $content; 
          ... 
 Calendar4.ics received, size = 78564 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also get some sort of encrypted file when using [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), however [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) works fine for me:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $fn = 'Calendar.ics';
my $url = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/XXXXXXXX/basic.ics';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $res = $ua->get( $url );
if ($res->is_success) {
    say "Saving file: '$fn'";
    open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
    print $fh $res->content;
    close $fh;
}
else {
    die $res->status_line;
}
```

Comment: @ikegami Click the three vertical dots next to the calendar in Google Chrome (at calendar.google.com/....), select "Settings and sharing", select "Integrate calendar" in the left menu, then copy the URL from "Secret address in iCal format"

Comment: The LWP::UA version of `$mech->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );` is `$lwp->get( $url, ":content_file" => $local_file_name );`, seeing as LWP::UA is the base class of WWW::Mechanize. And the LWP::UA version works, because the issue arises out of a header WWW::Mechanize adds. See my answer.